# How does a PostGIS query execute from database to the client side?

Tags: postgis

I am trying to understand how a query is executed from the postgis database to the client. Can someone explain this to me in layman's terms?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A broad question as the client can be many different things. In general it might work like the following examples.

A GI-System:

The query is sent from the GIS and run in the database. The result is sent back. How they communicate depends on the used driver to access the database.

The GIS runs a calculation on some table. But it is not run in the database but processed temporarily by the programs algorithms. The result temporary table is then converted into a query by the client(for example an UPDATE SET statement). With postgis this means usually many tables are processed in this query (or several of them actually) as you have the geometry tables. But this is all client side. The only thing that goes back to the database via the driver are "normal" queries. When you have access to the database you can see what queries are run when you work with your GIS.

A browser-based system:

A browser uses some programming language to show you webmaps (often JavaScript). But this is not what communicates with the database. The communication with the database is done by some program on the server where the database is. For example GeoServer or MapServer (the most common ones for geodata). They run the connection via some driver to the database and sending and reciving the queries. But they are no webservers themself (but GeoServer may be run without additional webserver as it has own code for it). They communicate with an Apache, Nginx or ILS-Webserver to send the "page" to the browser. For simple web maps this might be enough. But often you have another construct in between that processes the whole webpage (or more like an application). For example a PHP program running on the server that provides the page-functions. This communicates with mapserver and includes the map into the page and on the other way round it may provide the queries that are sent to database themself (often prepared queries that "run" behind a filter button for example).

In general for browsers there are many different scenarios as there are tons of frameworks with different programming languages, and several with geodata support. All parts are communicating with some sort of API or driver with each other that differ from application to application. One example might look like this:

browser with some geodata in a webmap (e.g. JavaScript) -> webserver (e.g. Apache) -> mapserver (e.g. MapServer) -> database or additional application (e.g. some PHP) and then database

Comment: The question is on PostgreSQL-client interaction, and this answer addresses computations done "not in the database" and JavaScript clients, neither of which are related to the question.

Comment: That was what i made out of the given picture that showed the whole stack.